# Creating div elements using .innerHTML gives unexpected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an array of Divs, but the below code runs incorrectly.

JS Code that runs incorrectly (actual JS below):
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/admWpm

```
var n=4;        //no. of Triangles
    var j=1; // j is just used to number the triangles
     for(var i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
        document.body.innerHTML+='<div class="row row'+i+'">';  //Open row div

        //Create squares
            for(var k=0;k<n;k++){
                if (k % 2 === 0) {  //Even squares
                    document.body.innerHTML+='<div class="square square1 '+(j++)+'"></div>';
                }
                else{               //Odd squares
                    document.body.innerHTML+='<div class="square square2 '+(j++)+'"></div>';
                }
            }
    document.body.innerHTML+='</div>'; //close row div
    }
```

Simplification of the output:

```
<div class="row row1"></div>
<div class="square square1"></div>
<div class="square square2"></div>
<div class="square square3"></div>
<div class="square square4"></div>
<div class="row row2"></div>
<div class="square square5"></div>
<div class="square square6"></div>
<div class="square square7"></div>
<div class="square square"></div>
```

The output I would like:

```
<div class="row row1"></div>
<div class="square square1"></div>
<div class="square square2"></div>
<div class="square square3"></div>
<div class="square square4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row row2">
<div class="square square5"></div>
<div class="square square6"></div>
<div class="square square7"></div>
<div class="square square"></div>
</div>
```

I think I'm using `innerHTML` incorrectly?

Comment: Why did you include the jQuery tag if your code doesn't use it?

Comment: FYI, the DOM is not a string of HTML. You can't create just an opening or closing tag using `.innerHTML`.

Comment: This is my 2nd attempt at JS (first time was a year ago). Thanks for the info.
I wasn't confident whether or not I was using JQuery or not, then I chose to click it since JQuery might be useful for an alternative implementation.
Sorry pros :/

Comment: Shame about the DOM - would you be able to suggest what I should do otherwise please?

Comment: Actually it's a good thing about the DOM. You have a simple hierarchy of objects to work with.

Comment: Could I be switching our of <script> to create the strings?

Comment: HTML in the DOM is ugly. I posed a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example using DOM methods to create and append elements.

```js
var n = 4; //no. of Triangles
var j = 1; // j is just used to number the triangles

for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  var d = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  d.className = "row row" + i;

  //Create squares
  for (var k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    var s = d.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    s.textContent = "i:" + i + ", j:" + j;
    s.className = "square square" + ((k % 2) + 1) + " " + j++;
  }
}
```

```css
.square {
  width: 70px; 
  height: 30px;
  margin: 4px;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  }
.square2 {
  background: red;
  }
```

The `square` classes in your code didn't seem to match your desired output, so you may need to tweak a little there.

I added a little text content and CSS to make it easier to view the output.

Comment: Thanks for this! Just trying to implement this into my more complex, actual problem (This way, I'll also really understand your code). Should be fine though, because this runs correctly.
Much appreciated!